# Issue with Express.js application using EJS template engine and router

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and currently studying Express.js. I have written a simple Express.js application with the EJS template engine and a separate router file. However, I am facing some difficulties, and I would greatly appreciate some help in resolving the issue.

Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./routes');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```

The problem I am encountering is that when I run the application, I'm not getting the expected behavior. The routes defined in my ./routes file are not working as I intended, and the EJS templates are not rendering correctly.

Specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Are there any potential issues with the code above that might be causing the problem with the router?
2. Is there a proper way to test the routes to ensure they are set up correctly?
3. How can I debug the application effectively to find the root cause of the issue?
4. Could there be any conflicts between the router and the EJS template engine that might prevent the templates from rendering correctly?

Thank you in advance for any insights and guidance you can provide. If you need any additional information, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Can you update your code piece with your routes.js file maybe there is problem in your export
And you need to call as `app.use("/", router);`